# Problem with Context API in SPFx when trying to retrieve list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I am currently refreshing my knowledge within SharePoint Framework, trying to show list items in list from Fluent UI using React as a framework.

Right now I am struggling with SharePoint Context API when trying to output data from a SharePoint List because I get this error message in my app:

[image]

Here are my code snippets:

My React component (**List.tsx**):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ICrudReactProps } from './ICrudReactProps';
import { DetailsList, IColumn } from '@fluentui/react/lib/DetailsList';
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';


export interface IListItemState{
    Title: string;
    ManufacturingCost: number;
    Retail_x0020_Price: number;
}

export interface IListItems{
    items: IListItemState[];
}

export class List extends React.Component<{}, IListItems> {
    private listColumns: IColumn[];
    private listItems: IListItemState[];
    constructor(props: ICrudReactProps) {
        super(props);

        // //Populate list items
        this.listItems = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                this.listItems.push({
                  Title: `TEST ${i}`,
                  ManufacturingCost: 12,
                  Retail_x0020_Price: i * 2,
                });
        }

        
        this.listColumns = [
            { key: 'column1', name: 'Title', fieldName: 'title', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
            { key: 'column2', name: 'Manufacturing Cost', fieldName: 'manufacturingCost', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true },
            { key: 'column3', name: 'Retail Price', fieldName: 'retailPrice', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizable: true }
        ];

        this.state = {
            items: this.listItems
        }
    }
    public _getListData() : Promise<IListItems>{
        return this.context.spHttpClient.get(
            this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + 
            "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tulips')/Items", SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
            .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
                return response.json();
            });
    }

    public _renderList(){
        this._getListData().then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            
        })
    }
 
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        console.log(this.state.items);
        this._renderList()
        return (
            <div>
                <DetailsList 
                    items={this.state.items}
                    columns={this.listColumns}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My main component(**CrudReact.tsx**):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './CrudReact.module.scss';
import { ICrudReactProps } from './ICrudReactProps';
import { List } from './List';

export default class CrudReact extends React.Component<ICrudReactProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ICrudReactProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.crudReact }>
        <h1>CRUD React</h1>
        <List />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the webpart entry code(**CrudReactWebPart.ts**):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'CrudReactWebPartStrings';
import CrudReact from './components/CrudReact';
import { ICrudReactProps } from './components/ICrudReactProps';

export interface ICrudReactWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}

export default class CrudReactWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<ICrudReactWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<ICrudReactProps> = React.createElement(
      CrudReact,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        context: this.context
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Interface code(**ICrudReactProps.ts**):

```
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

export interface ICrudReactProps {
  description: string;
  context: WebPartContext;
}
```

I appreciate if someone can help me sort out this problem, because I have done exactly like most people have shown how to do. Want to know where I have done wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create props interface for `List` component like:

```
export interface IListItemProps {
   context: any;
}
```

Use it in class declaration like:

```
export class List extends React.Component<IListItemProps, IListItems> {
   ...
}
```

Change `render()` in `CrudReact.tsx` like:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<ICrudReactProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.crudReact }>
        <h1>CRUD React</h1>
        <List context={this.props.context} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Then change API call in `List.tsx` like:

```
this.props.context.spHttpClient.get()
```